# Pycharm/Intellij debugger stop evaluating expression without closing debugger

Tags: python, debugging, intellij-idea, pycharm

I use the Pycharm debugger (which is strongly based on Intellij). I usually set a breakpoint and try some expressions using `alt + f8`. I execute a query using this evaluate expression mode, but this expression takes too long and I want to stop it.

How can I stop a query from evaluate expression without exiting debugger mode?

Comment: Just click the big red button to stop the debugger. It is located adjacent to the green play button.

Comment: This stops the entire debugging process, which I do not want. I just want to stop one specific query which I initiated through `alt + f8` ("evaluate expression").

Comment: AFAIK there is no UI to do this in IntelliJ/PyCharm.

Comment: I checked it with developers of IntelliJ/PyCharm and it indeed is correct that this functionality does not exist (yet?).